# Fill DataFrame Non-Zero Row Value with The Nearest Maximum Value and Reset After Zero Occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two MultiIndex column DataFrames, "Boolean DataFrame" and "Consecutive Boolean Count DataFrame".

The value of "Consecutive Boolean Count DataFrame" marks the number of consecutive boolean occurrence at corresponding position using `cumsum` (column axis, in forward direction). False is marked as zero. The number of consecutive boolean occurrence count from 1 again after zero value occurs.

I'd like to do something with "Consecutive Boolean Count DataFrame" like filling nearest maximum value in backward direction, and reset value to be filled after zero value occurs. Some behaviors are similar to `pandas.DataFrame.bfill` but not exactly the same. I can't find an API fully match the behavior.

The purpose is to mark number of consecutive boolean occurrence of different groups, show the last cumsum value in each consecutive boolean position in corresponding group. (One group refers to consecutive boolean value)

Boolean DataFrame:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Boolean** | **Boolean** | **Boolean** |
| 0 | True | True | True |
| 1 | True | False | False |
| 2 | True | True | False |
| 3 | False | True | True |
| 4 | False | False | True |
| 5 | True | True | True |
| 6 | False | True | True |
| 7 | True | False | False |
| 8 | True | False | True |
| 9 | False | True | True |
| 10 | False | False | False |

Consecutive Boolean Count DataFrame:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Boolean** | **Boolean** | **Boolean** |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Expected Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Boolean** | **Boolean** | **Boolean** |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Code:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 'Boolean' ] ] )

boolean_df = pd.DataFrame( [ [True, True, True ], 
[ True, False, False ], 
[ True, True, False ],
[ False, True, True ],
[ False, False, True ],
[ True, True, True ],
[ False, True, True ],
[ True, False, False ],
[ True, False, True ],
[ False, True, True ],
[ False, False, False ],
], columns=columns )

consecutive_boolean_df = boolean_df .cumsum() - boolean_df .cumsum().where( ~boolean_df ).ffill().fillna( 0 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
def max_streak(srs):
    groups = (srs!=srs.shift()).cumsum()
    streaks = srs.groupby(groups).transform("size")
    streaks[~srs] = 0 #streaks is 0 where the series is False
    return streaks

>>> boolean_df.apply(max_streak)
         A       B       C
   Boolean Boolean Boolean
0        3       1       1
1        3       0       0
2        3       2       0
3        0       2       4
4        0       0       4
5        1       2       4
6        0       2       4
7        2       0       0
8        2       0       2
9        0       1       2
10       0       0       0
```

To do all the above in one line, you can do:

```
>>> boolean_df.apply(lambda srs: srs.groupby((srs!=srs.shift()).cumsum()).transform("size").where(srs, 0))
```